# Acceder al valor "null" de column de datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Me gustaría poder acceder al valor de un campo calculado  de datatable.
En este ejemplo tengo la columna `"id"` y la columna null donde calculo el campo en base a otros dos (Una resta).  Ese campo null es al que quiero acceder  cuando hago doble click en la tabla. Accedo bien a todos los valores (Anque aqui solo pongo el valor `"id"`. pero no se como acceder al campo `"null"`
Lo he solucionado  accediendo directamente a la variable presupuesto.
alert(presupuesto); Tan simple como eso.

Columnas:

```
 "columns": [
    {"data": "id"}, 
    {
        "data": null,
        render: function( data ) {
            presupuesto= data.cnt - data.cnt_apr;
            presupuesto = presupuesto.toFixed(2);
            return presupuesto;
        }
    },
 ],


//Doble click en la fila para acceder al valor
$('#tblPrsp tbody').on('dblclick', 'tr', function () {
    var idPrsp = tblPrsp.row( this ).data();
    alert(idPrsp['id']); //Accedo a id
    alert(responsable); //Aqui me gustaría acceder a null
});
```

Comment: No estas creando una columna con nombre null, si no con uno de los valores a null. Por eso no puedes acceder a ella con  ['null']

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, Alguna sugerencia  de como acceder a ese valor?

Comment: Solucionado. Tan simple como hacer un alert(presupuesto) no se me habia ocurrido algo tan simple no.